# ASP.NET MVC 2 - how to get Ajax.BeginForm work properly inside partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a View with url like

> /Home/SetResults?patientId=[somePatientId]

, part of it gets conditionaly ajax-updated with some partialview

Inside of that partialView I have this code

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "Post"})) 
{%>
<div id="placeholder">
....
```

Whenever I press submit button I get to my simple controller action-method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(MyModel model)
{
 return PartialView();
}
```

Everything works fine except the ajax itself - instead of gettin my placeholder updated with the result of controller action I'm always getting redirect to a view with the url of

> /Home/Action

So, is it possible to partially update partial view? If yes what I'm doin wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to check would be that you are including the ajax script:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've noticed if this isn't included, submitting the Ajax form behaves like a regular submit.

Comment: Thankks alot! You saved my day :) Stupid me, forgot to add  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>